# Linear Algebra- Systems of Linear Equations

Tags: matrices

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&1&-1&2\\
      1&2&1&3\\
      1&1&(a^2-5)&a
    \end{array}
\right] $$

I saw this question on one of my slides. The answer says that the system has no solution if (a^2−4)= 0 and when a-2 is not equal to 0. How exactly did a-2 come about? And how do we know when the system has no solution, infinite solutions, and 1 unique solution?
If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Using row reduction of form $R_3 \to R_3 - R_1$ , $$\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&1&-1&2\\
      1&2&1&3\\
      1&1&(a^2-5)&a
    \end{array}
\right] \sim \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&1&-1&2\\
      1&2&1&3\\
      0&0&(a^2-4)&a -2
    \end{array}
\right]$$

If $a^2 - 4 = 0$ then $a - 2 = 0$ (back substitution) but if $a - 2 \ne 0$ then we get a contradiction and no solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

When the rank of the normal(3x3) matrix and rank of augmented matrix is equal to number of unknown variables,it gives unique solution.if rank is less than number of unknown variables , it will give infinite number of solutions.if rank of the normal(3x3) matrix and rank of augmented matrix are not equal, then it will give no solution.